# Is Feynman's Compton scattering diagram the same as the one in most books?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Feynman used the following Compton scattering diagram:

[image]

Whereas most books use this diagram in their derivation:

[image]

Is there a way to relate the two? Feynman's diagram makes more sense to me conceptually, but my professor used the second one in their derivation.

Comment: *"Whereas most books use this diagram..."* Most books? Which ones?

Comment: You are simply confusing those diagrams. A Feynman diagram is not the same as the latter diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagrams are different in that the on that occurs in "most books" is the one that occurs mostly in elementary treatments and is more in line with how the Compton effect was originally conceived historically, which was antecedent to Feynmann's work in Quantum Field Theory. Both diagrams do allude to things like momentum conservation, however, the Feynmann diagram is draw with a particular purpose in mind, viz. to aid in the calculation of perturbations in the QFT treatment of scattering problems, particularly the Wick expansion of the $S$ matrix. Because the Compton effect was derived before the advent of QFT, it managed to arrive at the correct result via incorrect theoretical foundations, nevertheless, the discovery was crucial in driving Quantum theory forward despite its theoretical shortcomings.